# php session_id doesn't seem to be uniformly distributed

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I received reports that people on my website ended up in wrong accounts. I trying to fix this. To cut the long story short I wrote a tracker for the session_id.

The results are frighting: `anzahl` means `number`

[image]

I don't have much traffic on my website, this is just the result after one day. I am pretty sure that this is the reason for my problem. This is a serious security problem!

How can I fix that?!

Comment: I don't get it. Are these fresh session id generations? How are you tracking them?

Comment: i write them in a database after the user logs in. I just use session_id(). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know how your login logout system works. If you don't destroy the session on logout the same session id can be re-used by the same user.

Comment: Check the code at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec6449595a6c13cff14e444f63d82a3c2fe39bcc and also http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-create-id.php. If there is a problem then running that code on your system should generate collisions.

Comment: @apokryfos I just save the session_id just after the login. during the session i don't save the session_id. I destroy the session if the user uses the logout button. Maybe session_create_id() can help.

Comment: If you're using [`session_destroy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) then note this: *In order to kill the session altogether, the session ID must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session ID (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.*. A user logging out and back in will re-use the same id if you don't unset the cookie.